# Ignore MSGTokenError in JAVACC

Tags: error-handling, javacc

I use JAVACC to parse some string defined by a bnf grammar with initial non-terminal G.
I would like to catch errors thrown by TokenMgrError. 
In particular, I want to handle the following two cases:

1. If some prefix of the input satisfies G, but not all of the symbols are read from the input, consider this case as normal and return AST for found prefix by a call to G().
2. If the input has no prefix satisfying G, return null from G().

Currently I'm getting TokenMgrError 's in each of this case instead.
I started to modify the generated files (i.e, to change Error to Exception and add appropriate try/catch/throws statements), but I found it to be tedious. In addition, automatic generation of the modified files produced by JAVACC does  not work. Is there a smarter way to accomplish this?

Comment: Can you add a code sample? And regarding Exceptions instead of TokenMgrErrors, see http://www.engr.mun.ca/~theo/JavaCC-FAQ/javacc-faq-moz.htm#tth_sEc3.19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always eliminate all TokenMgrErrors by including

```
<*> TOKEN : { <UNEXPECTED: ~[] > }
```

as the final rule.  This pushes all you issues to the grammar level where you can generally deal with them more easily.